# GCC DLL forwarded export using full file path

Tags: gcc, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to create a DLL forwarded export that specifies a absolute path. I've confirmed that doing so without a path works:

```
asm (".section .drectve");
asm (".ascii \" -export:DllForward=dummy.DllForward\"");
```

But when using a full path:

```
asm (".section .drectve");
asm (".ascii \" -export:DllForward=c:\\\\dummy.DllForward\"");
```

I get a symbol not found error:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>gcc -s -Os -o dllmain.dll dllmain.c -shared
c:/tools/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot export c:: symbol not found
```

I've tried a bunch of escape sequences, but none seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the value in a .def file or on the command line?

Comment: You could also try quotes: `-export:DllForward="c:\\dummy.DllForward"`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following .def file, as suggested by David:

```
EXPORTS
    DllForward="c:\\dummy.DllForward"
```

Which works as expected.